# Security in SPA with oAuth 1.0a , woocommerce usecase

Tags: ajax, api, http, oauth, single-page-application

I'm trying to implement an online application (single page) with angularjs in forntpage and wordpress + woocommerce plugin in backend.

For this purpose I'm installed WP RESTful API and activated woocommerce self api. and using angularjs resource for ajax calls with server.

The woocommerce API is protected by oAuth 1.0a protocol.

As I figured out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28337883/1589683) answer, the right way to request a protected API is just server side calls. So I created a new file in my server named "ApiCall.php" and wrote the whole secure communication stuffs in that.

Now my requests first send to "ApiCall.php" then the server communicate with woocommerce API (which is in the same server!) and the response will redirect to my angular code!

After all , now I'm confusing with this flow and security. When someone can request to woocommerce API, so he can request to "ApiCall.php" too! then the same security calculations will proceed for that person and result will returned to him!

On the other side, WP RESTful API have no security contraptions, and data are available with direct ajax calls.

I'm looking the best approach for this type of communications which a single page application want to get and set data to its backend.